# Store PHP Variable in CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to store my PHP variable in a CSV file.

As they are individual variables and I need to store them in row columns format.

for ex- ID, First Name, Last Name, Address, Phone. etc.

suppose I have variable $id, $firstname, $lastname, $address, $phone.

How can I store this variable in a single row separated by a column in a CSV file?

I tried using an array but as they are individual variables and use in entire my program so I want to add this variable at end of the script to CSV to maintain the report.

```
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

$fp = fopen("ouput.csv", w)

fputcsv($fp,array(array($id,$firstname, $lastname,$address,$phone)));

fclose($fp);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you tried. This isn't a coding service where we write all the code for you.

Comment: Did you want to store variable value or variable name to csv file?

Comment: I want to store variable value in csv, As first I am importing data from csv and storing into database. Then I want to store that variable which are inserted or updated using previous queries into csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got best Solution to separately save data column wise. 
fputcsv is able to handle large no of records very efficiently. also if the content with escape characters like , "" '' it will still add data properly in csv file ..

```html
fputcsv($csvfileoutput, array($id,$firstname,,$lastname, $address,$mobilenumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, instead of:

```
$fp = fopen("ouput.csv", 'w');
```

you should have called:

```
$fp = fopen("ouput.csv", 'a');
```

The `w` causes the file to overwrite, the `a` stands for append.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
$string = $id . "," . $firstname . "," . $lastname . "," . $address . "," . $phone;

file_put_contents("ouput.csv", $string."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Also not necessarily correct. this will 100% fail if your address contains a comma or newline for example. Pretty bad idea

Comment: This is a really bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check **[fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)** function in the manual.

From the example in the manual:

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```